# Change jQuery Dialog Window Position

Tags: jquery, html, css, user-interface, dialog

I'm using the Dialog from jQuery, http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message
It works perfectly fine, I just can't seem to move the dialog window's position.

How do I achieve this? I've tried looking for the code in it's CSS, tried inspecting the element and everything, it just won't budge.

What am I doing wrong? Where do I actually modify it?

Comment: Do you mean the ability to drag it around the viewport as per the demo? Or setting the position of the dialog when it initially shows?

Answer (score 6):

You can set the position by setting the `Position`

as

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dreadwarrior/3d7QC/12/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can set the "position" setting when constructing it:

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position

Answer (score 1):

if you want to drag this pop-up, just define

`draggable: true,`

if want to change position of pop-up just define vertical and horizontal position in

`position: ['center', 'top']`